# Are all infinite spaces compact?

Tags: general-topology

I took a topology exam a few days ago, in the correction from my professor, they said something sort of trivial to me. The exercise was
the following, we had a collection $\tau$, its elements are all subsets of R that do not contain {3}, R and the empty set are in $tau$ Is this a compact space? The only way I thought to do this exercise was by taking a finite collection of closed sets with the property of finite intersection, clearly, this would never be empty since all closed sets have at least {3} in common. The professor said that we could create an open subcover using the statement that the very space (R) was in the said collection of open sets that covers R, but this is kind of trivial to me. My questions are:
Is every infinite space compact?
In the subcover I have to use to cover the space, can I use the very space?
Are all finite spaces compact?
Why in the definition of an open subcover there is not a disclaimer stating that all open sets in the collection of said subcover are distinct from the space?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, a cover is a subcover of itself, so you can.

Comment: The space you've given isn't finite, so the question is strange to me.

Comment: Also, the fact that one open cover has a finite subcover does *not* establish compactness.

Comment: *The only way I thought to do this exercise....* What exercise? You described a collection $\tau$, good. But you did not state an exercise.

Comment: To the question in the title: yes, all finite spaces are compact.

Comment: In the title you are asking about compactness of infinite spaces, while in the body you are asking about compactness of finite spaces. Please specify your question.

Comment: "we had a collection τ, its elements are all subsets of $\Bbb R$ that do not contain $\{3\}$ Is this a compact space?" The answer is No. To be a space (much less compact), $\tau$ would have to have a topology defined on it, It is just some set. Okay, assume you said $\Bbb R$ with *topology* $\tau$, then it is still No. $\tau$ is not a topology on $\Bbb R$, as $\Bbb R \notin \tau$. Okay, suppose you add $\Bbb R$ to $\tau$, would that make it a topology? Yes. Is it compact? Yes, as any open cover must contain $\Bbb R$ as the only neighborhood of $3$, and $\{\Bbb R\}$ is thus a finite subcover.

Comment: What makes that work is not just that $\Bbb R$ is open, It is that this weird topology demands that every open cover of $\Bbb R$ has to include $\Bbb R$ as one of the open sets in it. Most topologies do not require such a thing.

Comment: I am truly sorry for my poor writing, I will make it better.

Answer (score 3):

The key feature of the topology $\tau$ is that its *only* element that contains the point $3$ is the whole set $R$ itself: by definition of $\tau$, if $U \in \tau$ and $U \ne R$ then $3 \not\in U$.

Now, suppose you are given an arbitrary cover $\mathcal U$ of $R$ by elements of $\tau$, that is to say, $\mathcal U \subset \tau$ and $\bigcup_{U \in \mathcal U} U = R$. That cover $\mathcal U$ must have an element $U$ such that $3 \in U$. But $U=R \in \tau$ is the only element such that $3 \in U$. Therefore, $R \in \mathcal U$. But $\{R\}$ all alone is an open cover of $R$. Therefore $\{R\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal U$. This proves that every open cover of $R$ has a finite subcover. Therefore $R$ is compact in this topology.

No, not every infinite topological space is compact. For example the real number line $R$ with its usual topology is not compact: the open cover $\mathcal U = \{(-t,t) \mid t > 0\}$ has no finite subcover. Notice $R \not\in \mathcal U$, so $\{R\}$ is not a finite subcover of $\mathcal U$.

Yes, every finite topological space is compact, because it has only finitely many subsets, therefore every open cover is **already** finite.

As for your final quesion "Why", no such disclaimer is necessary. The topology $\tau$ is very unusual, in that there is a very very special point $3$ having the property that the *only* element of the topology $\tau$ that contains $3$ is the whole space $R$ itself. This is an odd property for a topology to have. This property certainly is not satisfied by the usual topology on $R$.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mosher.